# What's the hash in packrat.lock for?

Tags: r, git, hash, package-managers, packrat

I'm setting up a git workflow with my R project using packrat. Everytime I `packrat::snapshot()` my workspace, the file `packrat.lock` changes with the new packages/versions etc, but it also changes the Hash line for each package, which is a bit annoying when checking file diffs to see what changed from one commit to another.

Is this Hash really necessary? If not, is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

The hash is generated by the hidden `hash()` function in `packrat` library, and it serves as a package consistency check.

The algorithm generates an `md5sum` that is based on the `DESCRIPTION` file included in the package tarball, but there is additional logic involved, see `lines #103-#107` in the [`packrat/R/cache.R`](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/blob/5173a3faea677b7b7f5ad46f6bbcbeabaef3e688/R/cache.R#L25) source at Github.

In order to obtain the HASH that `packrat` expects to find in the `packrat.lock` file a direct call to the `hash()` function must be made. This function is **not exposed** in the compiled package, so the only way to access it is to use the `packrat` source.

1. Obtain a copy of the source of the `packrat` library from CRAN with the correct version
2. Extract it into a folder (in my example it is `packrat-0.5.0`)
3. Start an R session

The following lines demonstrate how to generate the hash for the package `BH-1.66.0-1` (`4cc8883584b955ed01f38f68bc03af6d`):

```
# md5sum() function is neeeded
library(tools)

# relevant source code files are loaded
source('packrat-0.5.0/R/utils.R') # readDcf() function
source('packrat-0.5.0/R/cache.R') # packrat's hash() function

# execute the hash() function on the DESCRIPTION file in the package
print(hash('/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/DESCRIPTION'))
```

This should return the correct HASH of `4cc8883584b955ed01f38f68bc03af6d`.

I am not aware of any options in `packrat` that would allow you to disable HASH checking. If your goal is to manually modify the `packrat.lock` file to alter a package version, it is certainly possible by performing this trick.

This could help overcome some minor dependency issues. However, there are two dangers:

1. such a package version change may start a cascade of dependency upgrade requirements
2. errors appear in your app because of compatibility issues